# Fullcalendar adding events from mysql JSON - adding eventClick returns blank page

Tags: jquery, json, events, fullcalendar, jquery-events

I am pulling events into the calendar using JSON and PHP. I am know trying to add `eventClicks` or `mouseOver` events the the calendar and when I do I get a blank page. My JS knowledge is rather novice so at this point I'm stuck.

Here's my calendar script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     
  header: {
left: 'prev,next today',
center: 'title',
right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
},

editable: false,

events: "json-events.php",

loading: function(bool) {
 if (bool) $('#loading').show();
 else $('#loading').hide();
}

});

});
```

Pretty basic, and here's the JSON:

```
mysql_select_db($databaseDB, $connectItDB);

$sql= "SELECT id, title, description, url, email, Stime, Etime, eventDate, DATE_FORMAT(eventDate, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i' ) AS startDate
FROM events
ORDER BY startDate DESC";
$check = mysql_db_query($databaseDB, $sql, $connectItDB) or die(mysql_error());

$events = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($check)) {
$eventArray['id'] = $row['id'];   
$eventArray['description'] = $row['description'];
$eventArray['url'] = $row['url'];
$eventArray['email'] = $row['email'];
$eventArray['startTime'] = $row['Stime'];
$eventArray['EndTime'] = $row['Etime'];   
$eventArray['title'] =  $row['Stime'] . " " . $row['title'];
$eventArray['start'] = $row['startDate'];
$eventsArray['allDay'] = "";
$events[] = $eventArray;
}
echo json_encode($events);
```

I'm sure it has something to do with the I'm adding the events, any info will help that might tighten up the code but my main focus is being able to use `eventClick`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this:

```
mysql_db_query
```

should be:

```
mysql_query
```

making it like this:

```
$check = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Make also sure that you put these lines on top of your script to see if there are any errors coming up:

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Getting the info is not a problem its adding the evenClick that is supplied with the fullcalendar to work with the script I have. I'm almost sure its the  JQUERY script that pulls info from the JSON page. Theres really no formatting for the events, Thats the script I need and have no idea how to write it..